# Sale Tax Program with Functions

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code. Every time I compile my program, an error shows telling me that the syntax is not correct. Is this the correct syntax for a function?

```
sale=float(input("Enter the total sales price:"))
print("Cost of item: ", format(sale, '.2f'))
def main():
    c_tax()
    s_tax()
    TotalT()
    TotalC()
def c_tax():
    county_tax = sale * 0.02
    print("County tax: ", format(county_tax, '.2f'))
def s_tax():
    state_tax = sale * 0.04
    print("State tax: ", format(state_tax, '.2f'))
def TotalT():
    s = sale * 0.04
    c = sale * 0.02
    print("Total tax: ", format(s + c, '.2f')
def TotalC():
    state = sale * 0.04
    county = sale * 0.02
    TotalCost = sale + county + state
    print("Total cost of item: ", format(TotalCost, '.2f'))

main()
```

Here is the error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-17-176f54874857>", line 19
    def TotalC():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the function should have a parameter which sends the value of "sale".

Try this instead:

```
def TotalC(sale):
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your function, a variable 'sale' must be pre-set.

```
sale = 12
def TotalC():
    state = sale * 0.04
    county = sale * 0.02
    TotalCost = sale + county + state
    print("Total cost of item: ", format(TotalCost, '.2f'))

TotalC()
# 12.72
```

Otherwise., you need to pass it as an argument.

```
def TotalC(sale):
    state = sale * 0.04
    county = sale * 0.02
    TotalCost = sale + county + state
    print("Total cost of item: ", format(TotalCost, '.2f'))

TotalC(12)
# 12.72
```